# RoR: what are the benefits of erb in Rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I read an evocative post by Magnus Holm entitled [Block Helpers in Rails 3](http://timelessrepo.com/block-helpers-in-rails3), in which he points out that Rails 3 has bent the syntax of ERB too far.  (In 'original' ERB, an ERB construct can only span a single statement.  Rails 3 allows -- even requires -- spanning multiple statements.)

Which leads me to wonder: what are the real advantages to using ERB over Ruby's native string processing?  To dig into this, I took the example listed in the ERB documentation and tried it both in ERB and native Ruby strings.  It turns out that Ruby's rich library of string processing makes the translation really simple -- even intuitive.

Here's how it looks.  Common to both (lifted directly from the ERB documentation):

```
require "erb"

# Build template data class.
class Product
  def initialize( code, name, desc, cost )
    @code = code
    @name = name
    @desc = desc
    @cost = cost
    @features = [ ]
  end

  def add_feature( feature )
    @features << feature
  end

  # Support templating of member data.
  def get_binding
    binding
  end
end
```

Here's the template and the expansion written in ERB:

```
# ================================================================
# using ERB
erb_template = %{
    <html>
      <head><title>Ruby Toys -- <%= @name %></title></head>
      <body>
        <h1><%= @name %> (<%= @code %>)</h1>
        <p><%= @desc %></p>
        <ul>
          <% @features.each do |f| %>
            <li><b><%= f %></b></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
        <p>
          <% if @cost < 10 %>
            <b>Only <%= @cost %>!!!</b>
          <% else %>
             Call for a price, today!
          <% end %>
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
  }.gsub(/^  /, '')
rhtml = ERB.new(erb_template)
# Produce results
@r1 = rhtml.result(toy.get_binding)
```

And here's the template written in pure Ruby:

```
# ================================================================
# using native Ruby strings
ruby_template = %q{"
    <html>
      <head><title>Ruby Toys -- #{ @name }</title></head>
      <body>
        <h1>#{ @name } (#{ @code })</h1>
        <p>#{ @desc }</p>
        <ul>
          #{ @features.map do |f|
               "<li><b>#{f}</b></li>\n"
             end.join }
        </ul>
        <p>
          #{ if @cost < 10
               "<b>Only #{ @cost }!!!</b>"
             else
               "Call for a price, today!"
             end
           }
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
  "}
# Produce results
@r2 = eval(ruby_template, toy.get_binding)
```

These produce the same results (modulo whitespace).  Whether the ERB is simpler or more difficult is really a matter of taste and experience.  Judging from the number of questions about ERB and <%= ... %> vs <% ... %> vs <%= ... -%>, it appears that many people might have an easier time sticking to straight Ruby.

At the risk of starting some sort of holy war, why bother with a ERB when the native Ruby does the same job?  Do you think ERB is useful?  Should Rails accept "native Ruby" templates as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magnus Holm here; good to see that you enjoyed the article :-)

First let's have a look at templates (yes, interpolation is a template) as an evolution from constructing a string with regular code:

```
# "Regular" way of constructing a string:
str = "Hello World: "
@users.each do |user|
  str << "How are you today, "
  str << user.name
  str << "? \n"
end
```

If we look at this code, it's evident that there are three patterns that repeat themselves:

- We have plenty of *static* text which are appended: `str << "Static"`
- We have some *dynamic* code which are appended: `str << expresstion`
- We have some *blocks* of code which change the control flow: `@users.each`

The great thing about ERB is that it's a perfect isomorphism of these patterns, which means that the user can think of it in terms of constructing the string the regular way. It's simply a way to construct a string with more focus on the static parts (since they are common) than the dynamic parts.

As the "purist" you are, you've noticed that this is not the *lowest* level. That is completely true: As long as you can evaluate Turing complete code, your template engine becomes Turing complete and technically you don't need anything else. You don't need blocks when you can simply nest your template engine.

Now we need think about the difference between *low level* and *easy to understand*. Yes, as you remove building parts you end up with a smaller core, but that doesn't necessarily make it easier to understand. You could draw an analogy to GOTOs: You can create any looping/conditionals using one single concept (GOTOs), but it turns out that it's easier to reason about code with if/while-statements. Why? Because a *pattern* appears! Instead of conceptually parse these patterns every time we look at them, it's easier to create *abstractions* which we can understand instantly.

In your example, there's one pattern which I believe will be used in any template: `@users.map { |f| code }.join`. This is *exactly* what ERB tries to abstract away so you can forget about the details and reason about your logic instead.

I also believe that if you're making a template engine simpler, but still make it Turing complete, you will abstract away these details anyway. You will realize that a pattern emerges and, as the DRY coder you are, you will start creating helpers and such. You're actually implementing your own little template engine on top of another. Now everything depends on the syntax flexibility of the base language whether or not you manage to abstract away the real details without too much other noise. For instance, there are Lisp flavours which supports static typing and pattern matching, but often it can't beat a syntax designed especially for the problem.

So, *what are the real advantages to using ERB over Ruby's native string processing?* In one sentence: **It gives you nice syntax for common patterns.**

> Do you think ERB is useful?

Yes and no. I think interpolation is definitely *not* the right way. You will see patterns in your templates and nothing beats a custom syntax when it comes to templates. I think ERB is quite useful, but it lacks in some ways: It doesn't have the concept that blocks are also expressions:

```
# This block is more like a statement (we don't care about the return value)
@users.each do |foo|
  str << "Hello"
end

# This block is an expression
str << form_for(thing) do
  another_string
end
```

I have no idea if you can fix this with syntax, but right now it's "fixed" in each framework and there's no way to write block helpers that works across several frameworks. I'd love to see a more "official" way to deal with this.

> Should Rails accept "native Ruby" templates as well?

[Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt) already does, and the best solution would be if Rails switched over to Tilt, but I don't think "native Ruby" is that useful after all. If it's a short template, you can of course just use an interpolated string right in your code. And if it's a big template and you're going to move it out of your Ruby file, why not use a syntax designed for templates?

Answer (score 1):

Rails is opinionated software. It ships with a bunch of 'default' ways of doing things which I guess the core team agree is their preferred way of doing things - erb, Test::Unit, prototype, etc. but there's nothing to stop you changing these (more so with Rails 3).

In my opinion, erb in Rails, even though not quite like normal erb is far, far nicer than ruby string interpolation - especially when it comes to blocks. Having to break back into strings for the HTML within the block looks horrible to me.

But then again, haml looks horrible to me while others swear by it and hate erb. It's all down to your preference. That's why Rails makes it very easy for developers to create their own templating systems. I don't know if one exists, but there's nothing stopping devs from creating a templating system which uses solely ruby strings like that.

So, in answer to "Should Rails accept "native Ruby" templates as well?", it already does. So long as someone else implements it ;)

Comment: You should give haml another chance, it takes a while to grow on you but once it does it's hard to go back. I hated it until I found a textmate bundle for it.

Comment: @jonnii, I've used it a lot. A bunch of projects I still work on use it, and I can quite safely say, in my opinion, it's horrible. If I'm writing html, I want to use html. I have no problem writing clean html and using partials and helpers effectively. I don't have any problems reading well written html. Apart from a couple of vulgarities of ERB, I couldn't imagine wanting anything else in my templating system.

Comment: I like that it's less mark up because the nesting takes care of emitting the closing tags, but I know what you mean. Have you seen Razor the view engine for asp.net mvc? It'd be nice if we had something like that for rails.

Comment: I haven't seen that... It looks quite nice!